# How to make gradually changing background in CSS become uninterruptible?

Tags: html, css

My CSS goes like this (with the help of [this pen](https://codepen.io/metagrapher/pen/tgcLl)):

```css
div[class="heading"]  {
  animation: colorchange 50s; /* animation-name followed by duration in seconds*/
  /* you could also use milliseconds (ms) or something like 2.5s */
  -webkit-animation: colorchange 50s; /* Chrome and Safari */
}

@keyframes colorchange
{
  0%   {background: #e55f5f;}
  25%  {background: yellow;}
  50%  {background: #55CE91;}
  75%  {background: #5fe5e5;}
  100% {background: #ce71ae;} 
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorchange /* Safari and Chrome - necessary duplicate */
{
  0%   {background: #e55f5f;}
  25%  {background: yellow;}
  50%  {background: #55CE91;}
  75%  {background: #5fe5e5;}
  100% {background: #ce71ae;} 
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Some Sample Text Here... 
</div>
```

Everything goes perfectly well except that I want my DIV's gradually changing colors to be in cycle. It stops, ofcourse, after having to show all colors from the CSS. How can I make it uninterruptible? Thanks for all response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `infinite` to the `animation` in your css:

```css
div[class="heading"]  {
      animation: colorchange 3s infinite ; /* animation-name followed by duration in seconds*/
         /* you could also use milliseconds (ms) or something like 2.5s */
      -webkit-animation: colorchange 3s infinite ; /* Chrome and Safari */
    }

    @keyframes colorchange
    {
      0%   {background: #e55f5f;}
      25%  {background: yellow;}
      50%  {background: #55CE91;}
      75%  {background: #5fe5e5;}
      100% {background: #ce71ae;} 
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes colorchange /* Safari and Chrome - necessary duplicate */
    {
      0%   {background: #e55f5f;}
      25%  {background: yellow;}
      50%  {background: #55CE91;}
      75%  {background: #5fe5e5;}
      100% {background: #ce71ae;} 
    }
```

```html
<div class="heading">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Some Sample Text Here... 
</div>
```

Comment: Made it 3 seconds because I didn't want to wait for 10 seconds to see the loop.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes :) sure, no problem. I changed the original `50s` to `10s` :)

Comment: Didn't notice. Damn 50s

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot :) I'll be sure to accept this answer and keep a vote up